# Controlling styles in knockoutjs based on the values

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have two divs generated dynamically using knockoutbinding as follows:

```
<div id="simdivs" data-bind="text:$data.Name,visible:$data.Name !== undefined"></div>
```

I want to conditionally give a css styling as `"margin-left:1px"` if the data.Name from the second div is "" (empty) else `"margin-left:0px"`
how do I achieve this using knockout js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Style data-bind

```
<div id="simdivs" data-bind="style: {marginLeft: $data.Name === null ? '1px' : '0px'}></div>
```

Do note that it is written as `marginLeft` instead of `margin-left`